# BDE dbase Corrupt Memo/BLOB file

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dbf, dbase, bde

I am using Delphi 7 and BDE to access some DBase tables. Some dbt fikes end up being corrupted very often.
I know that closing the computer while having a dbase table opened leads to the corruption.
Does anybody have some ideas what other reasons might lead to this?

Comment: DBF is not a real standard. There are at least two major branches - Ahton-Tate/Borland and Clarion/FoxBase/Microsoft and an uncountable minor branches. Search for reverse-engineered "xBase format" documentations. BDE only works with their format and ignore others. Then those other programs you use work with their format and ignore others. And then minor differences are rolling up until the data is no more read. Personalyl i'd quit relying on long no more supported BDE and used some native DBF support like tDBF, VK-DBF or mem-DBF. If anything - that would allow you to debug and adapt them.